# remove additional sector in admin panel

Tags: section

after opening customer --> All customer --> edit --> addressees
[image]

so i want to remove this section
any ideas please ?
Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

first create custom module than create one xml file

```
app/code/AdamsMage/RemoveTab/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml
```

after add below code in file :

`<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> <body> <referenceBlock name="customer_edit_tab_view"> <referenceBlock name="address" remove="true" /> </referenceBlock> </body> </page>`

Comment: sorry but how can i found path in 'AdamsMage' ? 

app/code/AdamsMage/RemoveTab/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml